# Export selected fields in ArcGIS to Excel using Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, excel, field-mapping

I'm am creating a script that will allow a user to add XY coordinates to a point layer, then export (along with any addition user selected fields) to Excel. I am getting stuck on the iteration of the selected fields and how to map them to prepare to export to Excel. I have a parameter that derives the field names from the input point layer and the user can tick each field they wish to include in the Excel export.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your code to your question? This might help you to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I simply needed to split the field selections and then iterate through the list using field mapping.

```
paramInWells = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
paramInFields = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
paramInFieldList = paramInFields.split(";")
paramOutExcel = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Processing...")
arcpy.AddMessage("\nAdding XY coordinates")

fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()
for field in paramInFieldList:
    fieldName = arcpy.FieldMap()
    fieldName.addInputField(paramInWells, field)
    fms.addFieldMap(fieldName)

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(paramInWells, "in_memory", "XYCoords_Tmp", field_mapping=fms)

paramOutXyTemp = "in_memory\\XYCoords_Tmp"
arcpy.AddXY_management(paramOutXyTemp)
arcpy.AddMessage("\nCreating Excel document")
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(paramOutXyTemp, paramOutExcel)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you could try:

1. Make feature layer of your source field layer
2. Turn off fields or make them HIDDEN via the

> fieldInfo.setVisible()

Method sourcing from the user defined parameter.

[Turning fields on and off using arcpy](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/85543)

[FieldInfo (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000004v000000)

3. Finally, you may use the [Table to Excel](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000054000000) method for creating the excel table from the feature layer as the input table

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the built in tool "[export feature attribute to ascii](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p0000003v000000)". This is ascii file and not excel, but very easy to import in excel. It adds XY coordinates automatically and you can check the fields that you want to keep.